# How is a block used only for scoping called?

Tags: javascript, nomenclature, ecmascript-6

JavaScript has many types of block, such as `while` blocks, `if` blocks , `for` blocks. ES6 introduces block scoping, so "purely semantic", "anonymous" blocks make sense:

```
{ let a = 'I am declared inside a block'; }
console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

What is the above type of block (used only for scoping) called?

Comment: [Scope Cheat Sheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)

Comment: you call functions, not blocks. if you want callable logic, use [].map instead of for, boolean-return functions instead of if, and so on.

Comment: It is basically just like defining `a` in a function, it is only visible in inner scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the associated documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Block_scope_with_let_(Merge_into_let_Statement)

> The let statement provides local scoping for variables. It works by binding zero or more variables in the lexical scope of a single block of code; otherwise, it is exactly the same as a block statement. Note in particular that the scope of a variable declared inside a let statement using var is still the same as if it had been declared outside the let statement; such variables still have function scoping.

The documentation refers to it as a `let block`, `let expression` (if in an expression context), or `implicit block` in some cases.

---

In your example:

```
{ let a = 'I am declared inside a block'; }
console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

You cannot get the value of `a` outside of its scope. That is exactly what the scope is meant to do. However, you can do this:

```
{ let a; // instantiated inside this block
    a = 'I am assigned inside a block';
    console.log(a); // returns the value of a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that they are called `let` blocks. According to MDN I seem to be superficially right:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#let_statement

Read the "Scoping rules" section under `let` statement.

Comment: HOW are they called, not what

Comment: @RoryPickering Lol. I would never have known were it not for your comment.

Comment: @RoryPickering the question is incredibly vague. I think OP is actually asking what they are called.

Comment: @RoryPickering BTW the question has been tagged under "nomenclature". So I do believe the OP wanted to know "what" they are called. Plus "how to call a scope" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Fair enough, I was purely going off the OP's line `How is the above type of block (used only for scoping) called?`

Comment: I meant `what`, sorry for the confusion.